# How to use javascript Microsoft Authentication?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get Microsoft user informations like name and email after authentication but I'm a noob at javascript ! The code I use is here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa

I can configure the authentication page, but once the user is connected, how to redirect him to another page while transmitting his informations?

I thought about using `document.cookie = "user_mail = data.mail"` then `window.location.href = "mypageafterauthentication"` but :

1. Is this a secure solution? Is it not easy to modify Javascript code and insert bad informations in the cookies?
2. If this solution is good, where should I put the code in the example script?

Thanks a lot for your answers!

PS : I try to get the code in PHP but it uses Laravel and I don't know this framework. I work with Codeigniter... If someone also know how to use Microsoft Authentication with php I'll be happy to know how to do :)

Comment: To be honest though if you are redirecting the user from page to page it would probably make more sense to use a server-side authentication flow. JavaScript authentication is usually intended for scenarios involving a single-page application

Comment: Additional to @ADyson: Javascript is running on the client-side and can do things there. PHP is server-side. That said, these are two different ways which need things handled different. The way on client-side is to save the data and provide it to the server whenever needed (e.g. page-change). The way of the server-side is to identify the user and provide him with the data he needs. And that on every new landing-page he appears.You have mighty tools (e.g. sessions) to to that. But nevertheless you need to know what you are doing - means you need to learn programming. No way around :-)